# .loc slicing KeyError(f"None of [{key}] are in the [{axis_name}]")

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

So my original issue was a SettingwithCopyWarning, which I was trying to get around when I started getting this key error. Original (intended code) was:

```
df['Dates'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Dates'])
```

Which worked but gave me the warning of Setting a copy on a slice (exact warning was: A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame. Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead...)

So, trying to fix it, I did this:

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df.loc[df['Date'],])
```

and also this:

```
pd.to_datetime(df.loc[df['Date'],])
```

Which gives me this new warning:

```
KeyError(f"None of [{key}] are in the [{axis_name}]")
KeyError: "None of [Index(['10/1/2020', '10/1/2020', '10/1/2020', '10/1/2020', '10/1/2020',\n...dtype='object')] are in the [index]"
```

I also tried using the column but I get a syntax error:

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df.loc[,df['Date']])

SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I'm really stumped and trying to avoid my code from completely breaking over something that should be a simple converting string values in a column of Dates into a datetime format so I can sort it or filter on it properly. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

First of all the problem is on the left of the assignment. The warning says that it can't guarantee your assignment will change `df`. All the calculations on the right are OK.

The correct way to rewrite `df['Date']` with `loc` is `df.loc[:, 'Date']`. There is a confusion that for `loc` the first value in square brackets is responsible for rows not for columns. You need to write `:` to show you want to get all rows. Than comma and the column you want.

So the final code is:

```
df.loc[:, 'Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Dates'])
```